# WebApi Attribute Routing - simplest route does not work

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I have a very basic WebApi Controller as shown below, which uses attribute routing.

```
public class ValueController : ApiController
{
    //This route returns a 404
    [Route("api/v1/values")]
    public Value GetValue()
    {
        return new Value() { Name = "api/v1/values" };
    }

    //this route works fine
    [Route("api/v1/values/{valueId}")]
    public Value GetValueById(int valueId)
    {
        return new Value() { Name = "api/v1/values/{valueId}" };
    }

    //this route works fine
    [Route("api/v1/values/{valueId}/more")]
    public Value GetChildOfValue()
    {
        return new Value() { Name = "api/v1/values/{valueId}/more" };
    }
}
```

For some reason the first route returns a 404.
The other two both work as expected.

Attribute routing is turned on in WebApiConfig.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why the first route does not work???

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I called them and all worked correctly, maybe you are requesting /api/v1/value not value**s**

```
http://localhost:62138/api/v1/values
http://localhost:62138/api/v1/values/22
http://localhost:62138/api/v1/values/22/more
```